# Why does my programmatic approach to changing CSS animation duration not work?

Tags: javascript, css, promise, css-animations, css-variables

I have a collection of animations that have their duration assigned to a variable with the starting value of zero. After their first run (which is upon page loading), I would like to be able to change that duration to a non-zero value to get the animation effect I'm going for.

The following code *should* allow me to set the value of `--real-dock-animation-time` (what the animations use) to the value of `--dock-animation-time` after all of their first run, so that the previous value of zero can be changed to animate the desired changes only after the page is loaded.

```
let animationTimeDetermined = false;
function determineAnimationTime() {
  if (!animationTimeDetermined) {
    animationTimeDetermined = true;
    let r = document.querySelector(':root');
    let time = getComputedStyle(r).getPropertyValue("--dock-animation-time");
    r.style.setProperty('--real-dock-animation-time', time);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =>
  Promise.all(document.getElementsByClassName("dynamicHeader")[0].getAnimations().map((anim) => anim.finished)).then(
    determineAnimationTime()
  ))
```

What ends up happening, though, is it just appears as if it was the non-zero value to begin with and it animates on page load. How can I change the value only after I'm sure the animations' first runs are completed?

I have tried using setTimeout and parsing the CSS's non-zero value to milliseconds, but the imprecise nature of the timer system makes it flicker when the page loads.

If there's another way to get what I'm after that doesn't involve using JS to change the animation times, please let me know. The CSS's values are changed at the very beginning of the page's lifetime because I am setting attributes within the JS.

Comment: There's no reason for `determineAnimationTime` to be async, and so there's no reason to use `Promise.all`.

Comment: Thanks, I caught the former before you commented. It was residual of something else I tried and forgot to remove. Shouldn't Promise.all only execute .then after all of the promises are resolved? Because that's what I'm going for.

Comment: Look closer at the parentheses.

Comment: anim.finished is a promise. .then only executes after all of the items in getAnimations have fulfilled that promise

Comment: Next time I'll read the documentation properly :/

Comment: No hard feelings eh